# How to recognize double spaces and give meaning to them?

Tags: macros

I'd like to recognize two space characters and give my own meaning to it. Why does this not work and how can I fix it?

```
{\catcode`\ =13%make space active                                                            
\gdef\activespacetoken{ }%                                                                   
\gdef {\activespacemeaning}}
\def\activespacemeaning{\futurelet\peeknexttoken\activespacewithnexttokenmeaning}
\def\activespacewithnexttokenmeaning{\ifx\peeknexttoken\activespacetoken{T}{F}\fi}
\catcode`\ =13%                                                                              
Lorem Ipsum  is simply  dummy text.
\catcode`\ =10%make space space                                                              
\bye
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things are wrong in your code. Most importantly, when you do your `\ifx` test you need to remember that `\futurelet` will have `\let` your token `\peeknexttoken` to an active space not to what it expands to. So you need to set up a macro containing `\activespacemeaning` for comparison. Secondly, you have the primitive syntax for conditional branches wrong. Fixing both of those give us

```
{\catcode`\ =\active                                                            
\gdef\activespacetoken{ }%                                                                   
\gdef {\activespacemeaning}}
\def\activespacemeaning{\futurelet\peeknexttoken\activespacewithnexttokenmeaning}
\def\activespacetest{\activespacemeaning}
\def\activespacewithnexttokenmeaning{\ifx\peeknexttoken\activespacetest T\else F\fi}
\catcode`\ =\active                                                                          
Lorem Ipsum  is simply  dummy text.
\catcode`\ =10 %make space space                                                              
\bye
```